# Best way to reuse my own function in new projects?

Tags: python, function, import, module, package

What is the best way to easily add functions I make to new projects? I have made a bunch of python functions that I created myself that I use frequently for my projects, but I lose track of where I put them all and their versions become desynced when I change them

Should I just add all these functions to pypi? That seems time consuming, especially since a lot of these are pretty small.

I could also save the function as .py files and add them to the directories I make new projects on and import with a simple import. But the problem with this is if I change something about the original I would need to track down every instance of my function file and replace them with the new file.

I could also use absolute path imports, which I've looked at briefly. They seem pretty annoying for what they are, but that's maybe less of an annoyance than tracking down every copy of the file every time I change it. The other big problem with that is I do a lot of cloud computing, which would break my code every time I transition from running it locally to on the cloud, and force me to copy the code anyway.

Has anyone here run into a similar problem? Have you developed a nice solution to it? Is there an option I haven't thought of? All suggestions welcome!

Comment: Make it a package and install the package in the project environment

Comment: Use `sys.path` to add the directory containing your module to the search path in other projects.

Comment: Adding them to pypi and then `pip install` them in each project seems a good idea so you don't need to duplicate code for each project.

Comment: @d.b do you mean make it a virtual envirenment package with someone like pip install -e . ? Or do you mean to upload it to pypi as a package? Because the pypi part seems time consuming for some of these smaller functions

Comment: @SSCFan, I meant create a basic `setup.py` and run `python setup.py sdist` to make local package. If it's something that others can use too, then `pypi` could be good idea but is not necessary.

Comment: I would upvote this question but I'm at my daily vote limit currently. I think it's a good idea and ask, and the problem here is unfortunately there's no way to "automagically" update the util functions code in all the various projects, unless they're linked somehow of course.

Comment: @Barmar that seems like a really neat option. So you're suggesting for instance I put these functions in a folder then use sys.path.append('C:/Users/path/to/folder) and then import on my new projects?

Comment: One last suggestion I had would be to look into something like [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/) which allows you to define a template when creating new projects, so that existing code is then populated in the new project. Of course this does not work if you want to make changes to utils code in existing projects.

Comment: Something I did as an experiment was make a package of functions and then move that folder into my Python libraries directory, making the set of functions available to all projects (used this site: https://timothybramlett.com/How_to_create_a_Python_Package_with___init__py.html). Don't know if it would cause problems or not, but thats my 2 cents :)

Comment: @Party-with-Programming this seems like a neat option, but potentially not great practice. Like could this potentially cause problems? I'd be interested to hear from people more knowledgeable than myself

Answer (score 1):

Here's basic example to create a local package.

### Folder Structure

```
root/
├─ mypackage/
│  ├─ __init__.py
│  ├─ func.py
setup.py
```

#### `__init__.py`

```
from .func import foo
```

#### `setup.py`

```
from distutils.core import setup


setup(name="mypackage",
      version='1.0',
      description='',
      packages=["mypackage"],
     )
```

#### `func.py`

```
def foo():
    print("foo")
    return
```

### Steps

#### Build and Install

Run following in terminal. **Activate your project environment beforehand**.

```
cd root
python setup.py sdist
pip install ./dist/mypackage-1.0.tar.gz
```

#### Usage

Activate your environment first. Then run following in python console:

```
>>> import mypackage
>>> mypackage.foo()
# foo
```